# Do I need beetailer.js in rwd 1.9 ?

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd

It's slowing the loading process. Why do I need beetailer.js in rwd 1.9?

Answer (score 1):

That is **not** part of default Magento rwd template.

It is probably added by an extension for **Beetailer Facebook store**. So if you are not using that extension you can just deactivate it and this file won't be loaded anymore.